# What is the opposite of url_for in Rails? A function that takes a path and generates the interpreted route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing, actionpack

Brain's a little fried....How do I get a hash of the :controller and :action from a relative_path?

This is basically the opposite of url_for. in the example below, "some_function" is the mystery function name I'm looking for...I know it's easy, just can't remember or seem to be able to find it in the docs.

Like so:

```
some_function('/posts/1/edit')
=> {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'edit', :id => '1'}
```

Comment: Are `controller.action_name` and `controller.controller_name` sufficient? Or do you really need to manipulate generic relative paths from "outside" your current controller/action?

Comment: I do...unfortunately. Thanks though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rspec has a method 'params_for', which uses Action Controller's Routing Methods to parse paths with methods into routes.

Theirs is a little more robust than this, but it boils down to:

```
def params_for(path, method)
  params = ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(path, :method => method)
end
```

Comment: You may get a deprecation warning when using ActionController::Routing::Routes

Comment: Please provide source link for the `params_for` method

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` works with Rails 3.2

Answer (score 10):

With Rails 3 the best way is to use

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/posts/1/edit')
```