# Path parsing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, routes

I am looking for method for parsing route path like this:

```
ActionController::Routing.new("post_path").parse
#=> {:controller => "posts", :action => "index"}
```

It should be opposite to `url_for`

**Upd**
I've found out:
[What is the opposite of url_for in Rails? A function that takes a path and generates the interpreted route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222522/what-is-the-opposite-of-url-for-in-rails-a-function-that-takes-a-path-and-genera)

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path("/posts")
```

So now I need to convert `posts_path` into "/posts"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's this method:

```
>> ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path("/posts/")
=> {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
```

If you only have a string with your route (like `"posts_path"`), then I guess in the context you're using this you should be able to do

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(send("posts_path".to_sym))
```

btw this was educating for me too :)

Comment: Thx :) so what is `send(:post_path)`?

Comment: it's how you call methods with an arbitrary name in ruby :) in this case, if you have a string like `"posts_path"`, and you want to get the value of `posts_path` method instead, then you just do `send("posts_path")` (you don't even need to convert to symbol). it's a core concept in ruby, you'd better be familiar with that :)

Comment: ok, thanks, I've got it. I know how `send` works (like eval in this case). But problem was in console (I've just tried `ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(send("post_path".to_sym))`) so I've got confused because that failed :)

Answer (score 12):

In Rails 3 you can do the following:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/accounts/1"
# {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts", :id=>"1"}
```

Using `ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path` kept throwing

> ActionController::RoutingError Exception: No route matches "/accounts/1

Comment: Note this also works with full URLs: `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path 'http://example.com/accounts/1'`